# What did Peace Corben do to the Puppeteers?

Tags: larry-niven, known-space

In the short story "Peace and Freedom" Peace Corben sent a message to the Puppeteers by way of the Outsiders threatening the Puppeteers with extinction.

> “[...] Your interference is offensive, but your irresponsibility is toxic. In the event that you inflict either upon humans, or their associates, ever again, you will be rendered extinct. Message ends.”

When the appalled Outsider asked Peace what she had done, she responded:

> “[...] I set up my arrangements over three hundred years ago.  [...] “*I don't know.*  I expected to have this conversation someday, and I knew you could do a brain readout, so I erased it from my memory.”

Roughly a year after she turned Protector and a few hundred years before that conversation with the Outsider, Peace said this to Buford Early (in the short story "Leftovers"):

> “I planted some surprises in the Puppeteer when I put him back. Have to erase my own memories of them before I talk to any Outsiders, of course, but I can promise you if they’re still in contact with us in five hundred years they’ll be much too busy to manipulate human lives.”

**Which Puppeteer did Peace Corben kidnap and what did she do to him?**

I had hoped that "Peace and Freedom" might tie into the bedlam at the end of *Fate of Worlds*, but the threat of extinction was issued in the 2980's (as near as I can tell), and *Fate of Worlds* wrapped up in 2894.

Comment: Peace and Freedom wasn't written by Larry Niven but by Matthew Harrington. So how canonical it is...

Comment: I don't know.  But if Niven didn't like what Harrington was doing, I doubt there would be so many stories by him in the Man-Kzin series.

Comment: The canonicity of the stories is addressed in the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-Kzin_Wars but to summarize: at least one is, at least one isn't, and the rest haven't really been addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The puppeteers' breeding hosts will develop intelligence when they come into contact with the least trace of hominid/primate DNA. Don'tcha just LOVE nanotech? - MJH

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! First of all, are you claiming to be Matthew Harrington, the author of this story? Second, how does this answer the question of "Which Puppeteer did Peace Corben kidnap and what did she do to him"?

Comment: No special claim; just so happens. I didn 't have a specific P in mind, as I had no idea which ones were available. I'm affraid I was answering the original question.